# weblogic applications sharing a session cookie

Tags: rest, session, jakarta-ee, websphere, weblogic

I have two applications on one weblogic server, and they are making REST requests on the same server (WebSphere).

The applications are in cluster, and when application users create request they often receive **response 500, internal server error**.

From WebSphere's logs I receive:

`(00001715 WASSessionCor E SessionContext checkSecurity SESN0008E: A user authenticated as user:XXX has attempted to access a session owned by user:YYY.)`

The websphere admin says that my applications receive a same `jsession` id cookie when making a request, and therefore I get session collisions.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure different session cookie paths or names for different applications on websphere.
Take a look at page 8: http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4580.pdf

Anway, you shouldn't have a session on a rest service.